# Dynamic sorting But Variable Name Undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting

I need to set a dynamic sort data table using button.When I click button to sort it come out error like this. 
`ERROR TypeError: "this.aName is undefined"`. Whereas, I've declare it first like this `@ViewChild('aName') aName:ElementRef;`. I've provided the full code for your reference.

**HTML**

```
<mat-chip (click)="test('aName')">
 <mat-icon class="icon icon-filter"></mat-icon>Sort
</mat-chip>
```

**Component ts**

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
@ViewChild('aName') aName:ElementRef;

test(val){
  console.log(val)
  switch(val) {
    case "aName": { 
      this.aName.nativeElement.click()
      this.aName.nativeElement.click()            
      break; 
      } 

  }
  this.Nameservice.getNameService(this.pageIndex).subscribe(res =>{
    console.log(this.pageIndex)
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<NameDetails>(res);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

    const sortState: Sort = {active: val, direction: this.sort.direction === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc'};
    this.sort.direction = sortState.direction;
  this.sort.sortChange.emit(sortState);

  });
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.sort.sortChange.subscribe((x) => {
    console.log(x);
  });
}
```

Hope you all can help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars) (`#aName`) in your HTML in order to use it with named selector. You can do it like following:

```
<mat-chip (click)="test('aName')" #aName>
 <mat-icon class="icon icon-filter"></mat-icon>Sort
</mat-chip>
```

But I don't understand why you are doing `this.aName.nativeElement.click()` and why twice. This will create an endless loop.

Comment: Thank you so much dude... it work!.. I using this `this.aName.nativeElement.click()` twice because  to call `ngAfterViewInit()`. Single it does not work